# Sum based on row number in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

Sorry if the title is inappropriate.Let me explain what am trying to do. I have a calender table which i used for fetching data from my sales table. Here is the resulting table.

```
SoldQty  StandardDate   RowNum
1        2013-10-30     1
5        2013-10-31     2
1        2013-10-30     3
1        2013-10-31     4
4        2013-10-30     5
1        2013-10-31     6
2        2013-10-31     8
1        2013-10-31     9
```

What i need is the sum based on row number i need the sum of values of first three rows,then the next three and the last 3. Is there a way to achieve this or should i insert this into a temp table and write select statements based on the row number. Thanks in advance

Update:

Expected output should be like this

```
Sold 
1.4   ->(sum of 1 to 3)*.20
1.8   ->(sum of 4 to 6)*.30 
2     ->(sum of 7 to 9)*.50
```

or just

```
  Sold 
  5.2 -> sum of all the above values
```

Comment: create an extracolumn as rowNo, then use OVER and PARTITION BY to calc sub-results. Group 'em as having the equal integer result of division by 3

Comment: @jim i already have a row number in the table as shown above .Will look into partition by have never used that. not much of a sql guy :(

Comment: ah, sorry. Btw, check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx sample B. You only need to partition by /3 division result

Comment: @AmitSingh a table or something that has values for each sum based on row number

Comment: Here is your query: `select sum(SoldQty)  from t group by  (RowNum-1)/3;` [approach in sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fffa0/1/0)

Comment: @jim, is your query, be free to post it. Regards.

Comment: @danihp is there a way i can multiply a value to the first group by (i.e first 3 rows ),second(next 3),and last 3 rows

Comment: see @AmitSingh comment, post your expected output. Also explain how many rows your calendar table can grow.

Comment: you should use case statement: `sum( SoldQty * case ([numrow]-1/3) when 0 then 0.2 when 1 then 0.3 when 2 then 0.3 end ) from t` without group by.

Comment: @danihp  it brings 0 .I have created a sql fiddle can you please take a look  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75ea7/2

Comment: you forgot brackets () : `CASE ( ([RowNum] - 1 ) / 3)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40718/discussion-between-danihp-and-karthik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final query you are looking for is:

```
select 
   sum( SoldQty * case ( ( [numrow]-1) /3) 
                  when 0 then 0.2 
                  when 1 then 0.3 
                  when 2 then 0.5 
                  end ) as result
   from [yourCalendarTable]
```

Notice than  `( [numrow]-1) /3` is an integer but a decimal because you operate with integers.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to group result, you must have a group to do that ;-).

For you case you can use the column `RowNum`. The trick is to translate the sequence into grouped values.

```
1 - 0
2 - 0
3 - 0

4 - 1
5 - 1
6 - 1
```

This is quite easy to do with math. `(RowNum -1 ) / 3` will do the trick.

So the query for you is

`select count(SoldQty) from table group by (RowNum -1 ) / 3`

Answer (score 1):

The query below will give you the sums by categories you described:

```
DECLARE @maxRowNumber INT

SELECT @maxRowNumber = MAX(RowNum)
FROM   Data;

WITH Sums(Description, Total)
     AS (SELECT 'Sum of 1 to 3',
                SUM(SoldQty) * .20
         FROM   Data
         WHERE  RowNum <= 3
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Sum of 4 to 6',
                SUM(SoldQty) * .30
         FROM   Data
         WHERE  RowNum >= 4
                AND RowNum <= 6
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Sum of '
                + CAST(@maxRowNumber-3 AS VARCHAR(10))
                + ' to '
                + CAST(@maxRowNumber AS VARCHAR(10)),
                SUM(SoldQty) * .30
         FROM   Data
         WHERE  RowNum >= @maxRowNumber - 3)
SELECT *
FROM   Sums
```

To get the sum of the values from categories, replace `*` with `SUM(Total)`

Answer (score 0):

Take count(*) and store it in one int variable. then use the method "danihp" said above.
                                 OR
Add one more column with identity take Max(identity_field) then use the same method.